# Can A Google Apps Script Retroactively Set The Google Drive indexableText attribute For Uploaded Files

Tags: google-apps-script, text, google-drive-api, markdown, obsidian

TLDR: Google Drive does not index markdown files or mime type text/markdown by default. I'm looking for a way to make sure that all files in a specified directory are being indexed by Google Drive.

I have applications on Windows desktop and Android mobile such as Obsidian and Markor that saves markdown document files (.md) to a Google Drive folder with a mime type of text/markdown.

When I attempt to search for terms in the content of the markdown files from the Google Drive website, they do not appear to have been indexed and cannot be found. I can only find terms in the filename of the markdown files.

I can create a text document (.txt) with the same content as the markdown file and they are saved to Google Drive with a mime type of text/plain. The content of these text files are indexed and can be found using search on the Google Drive website.

I came across the following article indicating that there is a way via the Google Drive API/SDK to mark a special Google Drive attribute called indexableText to 'true' for mime types that are not indexed by default by Google Drive.

https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/how-to-make-files-searchable-in-google.html

It states, "We recently added a way for you to indicate that the file you are uploading is using a readable text format,".

The excerpt indicates that this method is meant to be used as the files are being uploaded.

My question is whether it's possible to set the indexableText attribute to 'true' on existing files or after the files have already been uploaded?

My goal is to have a script that is either triggered by the creation of a new file or that runs at regularly scheduled intervals to make sure that all files in a specified directory are being indexed by Google Drive.

If there are already apps, scripts or services that provide this functionality, I would welcome your recommendations.